# ExtJs Don't find Property to Map String Collection

Tags: extjs, combobox, mapping, jsonreader

I return a list of string for the combobox that serialized look like:

```
data:{"option1", "option2", "option3"...}
```

JsonReader have a list of fields, lets said we want to map to a OPT field:

```
reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({...
   fields: [ {name: 'OPT', mapping: '???'} ]
})
```

I understand that mapping should be point to the property name... but string doesn't have value/content property.

Answer (score 0):

What you have supplied isn't valid JSON.

It either needs to be (use an Array Reader)

```
data: ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"]
```

Or (mapping would be "name")

```
"data": [{
    "name": "option 1"
}, {
    "name": "option 2"
}]
```

Comment: How Array Reader work?... still we need something to map the field, what it is???